# Is there any advantage in having a rare player in my squad?

Tags: fifa-13

FIFA '13 Ultimate Team provides us some "rare" players, which are identified by bright  cards.

But what makes a player rare? Are they rare because of any specific attribute, such as strength, acceleration, pace, dribbling or whatever, which would add some real value to a player because he is different from the others, or because they are just artificially uncommon, which would surely make them rare but would not add any value to the player?

For example, I could consider a player rare for having an enormous ball control, much greater than the average. But I'm not sure this is how it works in FIFA 13.

I've played against some squads formed completely by rare players and yet I can't see why it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Rare cards do not have any benefit over non-rare cards.

The follow extract is taken [from here](http://www.fifauteam.com/fifa-ultimate-team-players-cards-explained/):

> Within the category of regular cards there is a variant which is
>   distinguished by its bright and luminous aspect. Are called Rare
>   Cards. These cards meet the need that EA had to make some cards more
>   common than others. Does not necessarily mean that they are most
>   valuable cards.
>
> A player can not have associated with him a regular rare card and a
>   regular not-rare card.

Comment: Aren't you confusing "rare players" with "in form" players? Because in fact IF players are improved versions of regular players; rare players are just rare. For example Tulio de Melo (http://www.futhead.com/fifa/players/3080/) is a rare player -- there is no other version for him, just the rare one (of course there can be an IF version in the future). So: is Tulio de Melo better than other players the same rate (77) just because he is rare?

Comment: @PauloGuedes: Sorry, you are correct, I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no because high rated players rated 81 82 83 84 85 ect are the best players to get but other lower rated players are good and they make your squad look nicer aswell

Comment: But there are rare players with several different rates. What I want to know is: a normal player rated 82 would be worse, better or equivalent to a rare player rated 82?

Comment: @PauloGuedes no, a normal and rare player rated at 82 are both equally rated overall - although they could both have very different attributes

Comment: @AnthonyBlake I got your point, yet I can't see what makes a player "rare". :/

Comment: @PauloGuedes there are less of them available